# How to get image form Partial NSdata in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsurlconnection, nsdata

I would like to show Progressive download to user, So I'm using `NSURLConnection` delegates.

I'm downloading large images of resolution around **1000x1000** and I’m showing it in **220x220**  image view. Now how can I generate the image form the data (not full data).

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.appRecord.cakeURL]];
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.activeDownload appendData:data];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:self.activeDownload];    
}
```

Im getting this error.

```
<Error>: ImageIO: JPEG JPEG datastream contains no image
```

Please help me.

Comment: you can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) if you want to show progressive download of image. It gives you caching functionality also.

Comment: I already used SDWebImage, Getting some problems with memory. So want to do my own, Cahing and downloading normally is fine, Just if suppose half part of image is downloaded i want to show it before downloading full image

Comment: Have you cross check image url in browser that it returns an image?

Comment: Yes Im getting images after full download, but i want to get the image up to the downloaded part..

Comment: The method `imageWithData :` was not suppose to work for partial data, to show half image (downloaded from server) you need to go to deep down lower API - I prefer language C, C++. Create your own class that create image from received bytes.